# C# template method which changes logic at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

I am writing a method in c# class as shown below:

```
using(sftpClient)
{
    sftpClient.Connect();
    try{
        //Do some process
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    sftpClient.Disconnect();
}
```

I need to create some more methods similar to the above but the logic changes only inside the try{} catch{} block. Can anyone suggest some best way to achieve this using some design pattern?

Comment: sftpclient.Disconnect() in finally block would look better

Comment: @sll I'd say class should just call `Disconnect` in `Dispose` rather than writing `finally` by hand... But indeed `Disconnect` (or `Close`, `Flush` or explicit `Dispose`) look strange inside `using`.

Comment: To use a design pattern that is better than the code above you should have given information about the use case and the SFTP client that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an abstract base class:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
   protected abstract void DoSomething();

   public void DoSmtpStuff() {
       smtpClient.Connect();
       try {
           DoSomething();
       } catch (Exception ex) {

       }
       smtpClient.Disconnect();
   }
}
```

and then just create inheritances of that class, which implement only the `DoSomething` method.

Comment: Might be helpful exposing abstract method which called in catch() like HandleError(Exception ex)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [`Strategy Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (emphasis my own):

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
>   policy pattern) is a software design pattern that enables an
>   algorithm's behavior to be **selected at runtime**.

So basically, you would declare an interface, say, `IBehaviour` and define some method:

```
public interface IBehaviour
{
    void Process();
}
```

Then have a different class implement `IBehaviour` for each piece of logic you want to have.

The class where you need to consume the logic would then allow passing an `IBehaviour` object and in your `try` block just do `behaviour.Process()`.

This will allow you to set up the behaviour from outside the class and then simply pass it along to the class in which you want to actually do something with it.

Comment: I think he should use template pattern not strategy becuase part of his code(some steps)is changing  not all algorithm inside method

Comment: @Arashjo: So something like abstract classes?

Comment: yes somehow,google about the differences between those

Comment: @Arashjo: I see no real difference between using interfaces and abstract classes (conceptually) for this type of thing. Both approaches rely on the fact that there is some class which implements an abstract behaviour, which is called by someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to classes is just take Action as argument:

```
TResult WithSftpClient<TResult>(Func<TResult, SftpClient> operation)
{
  TResult result = default(TResult);
  // Note that one may need to re-create "client" here 
  // as it is disposed on every WithSftpClient call -
  // make sure it is re-initialized in some way.
  using(sftpClient)
  {
    sftpClient.Connect();
    try
    {
        result = operation(sftpClient);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       // log/retrhow exception as appropriate
    }
    // hack if given class does not close connection on Dispose
    // for properly designed IDisposable class similar line not needed
    sftpClient.Disconnect(); 
  }
  return result;
}
```

And use it:

```
  var file = WithSftpClient(client => client.GetSomeFile("file.name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
abstract class ProcedureBase<T>
{
    public T Work()
    {
        using(sftpClient)
        {
            sftpClient.Connect();
            try{
                ProtectedWork();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
            sftpClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }
    protected abstract T ProtectedWork();
}


class Procedure1 : ProcedureBase<TypeToReturn>
{
    protected override TypeToReturn ProtectedWork()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

class Procedure2 : ProcedureBase<AnotherTypeToReturn>
{
    protected override AnotherTypeToReturn ProtectedWork()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Procedure1 proc = new Procedure1();
    proc.Work();
}
```

Comment: Ugly naming to be honest, why class has "Procedure" prefix? "Protected" prefix for protected method... Also generic parameter complicates example and slightly shifts emphasis from main question. Method "Work" is noun but method names better looks as verbs whereas nouns good for properties